# adding a new hard drive for data under linux with zfs

Tags: zfs, automount

I cannot get my `zpool` dataset to preserve and mount after reboot

I am sure I am missing something basic, but here goes:

I have Linux (Artix) installed on `/dev/sda` as ext4.  Note: Artix does not use systemd.

I would like to add a data drive using `zfs` for snapshotting and software RAID.

I am testing my setup in Virtualbox before I commit to hardware (if that matters).

So I have `zfs` successfully installed

Tested with:

```
$ zpool status
```

I create my first pool

```
# zpool create tank -o ashift-12 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_XXXX
```

I create some datasets

```
# zfs create tank/data
```

Scrub for good measure

```
# zfs scrub tank
```

and here is where I am not sure what to do... I think I need to add something to `fstab` but not sure what?

If I reboot here all is lost.

I can get it back by doing

```
# zpool import tank
```

What is the right way to get this set up to auto-mount?

Comment: Not familiar with ZFS, but up til what you mentioned, it doesn't sound like you are talking about (auto) mounting, but the preparation to "populate" the block device for mounting into the system. In a systemd-distro, usually this is done with udev rules and/or systemd services. (Often upstream / the distro will already have them written to cover usual scenarios, like the case of LVM. You might want to check if the OpenZFS / ZFS-on-Linux project or the downstream package maintainer / provider provides any or suggest any approach.)

Comment: What distro are you using?  Does it use systemd?  There are units you need to enable/start.

Comment: @Zoredache A am actually using Artix which does not use systemd.  my init system is runit